Is it possible to get something from another classpath with the getResourceAsStream method?
enter image description here
inputStream = DrawManager.class.getClassLoader()
       .getResourceAsStream("graphics");

I would like to load “graphics” from the res folder with the code in line 74 of the photo.(The path for this code is src, not res)
However, for some reason a nullPointerException error occurred.
It said inputStream is null.
Is it possible that this method cannot import something from another classpath? So what should I do?
I tried putting "graphics" in the src folder, but an error occurred.
Why did an error occur?

Please post the code as text, not screenshot.

That image looks to be of IntelliJ. Try marking res as a "resource root". Does that help at all? Note typically resources are copied from their source directory to the output directory (and eventually packaged in the same JAR file as the class files). If the resources end up in the same directory as the class files, or both are in a JAR file, then the resources will implicitly be on the class-path alongside the code. Otherwise, the resource directory can be put on the class-path separately. Though if you make res a "resource root" I would expect IntelliJ to handle all this for you.

There is only one CLASSPATH, and with getResourceAsStream(), you can read only from that CLASSPATH.
Resources that are stored elsewhere are not found, causing that null is returned by that method.
To solve your issue, you either use a FileInputStream with the full path to your resource, or you add the folder with your resource to the CLASSPATH.
Assuming that your file graphics is in the folder /home/you/resources, the first solution would look like this:
inputStream = new FileInputStream( "/home/you/resources" );

For the second solution, you start your program like this, assuming that the class with main() is MyClass, that it is located in the current folder, and that you do not need any other libraries:
java -cp .:/home/you/resources MyClass

